# Why hikariCP required with spring boot application?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

We have added dependency in maven `pom.xml` for HikariCP with our Spring Boot application, but I am not sure about the benefit for this. We are using `JdbcTemplate` for the DB access.

Can anyone please share the benefit of HikariCP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[HikariCP](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) is a JDBC connection pooling library while [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) is a Spring Framework class used to simplify the SQL operations in your application code. You are comparing apples to oranges.

You most likely need some kind of JDBC pooling library if your application connects to a database, unless you can manage this entirely with the JDBC driver options. The JDBC pooling library is there to provide a number of functionalities:

- Throttling the number of open connections
- Checking for stale connections
- Reconnecting and managing connection state

Starting from Spring Boot 2.0 HikariCP is the default solution, previously it was tomcat-jdbc. More on this change [in the official Spring Boot 2.0 migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#configuring-a-datasource).

Comment: Is there anyway not to use Hikari cos I just want to use MySQL

Comment: @KarenGoh if you are writing a simple app that only opens a few connections and runs short queries twice a day it's fine to use just the MySQL driver. In other cases you need something to manage connections, a connection pool like HikariCP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I didn't know about that.  Tks alot!

Comment: Best answer in the world.